# ActiveRecord retrieve items by own attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to retrieve specific items from my DB using and ActiveRecord Model in my Rails 5 application. The table looks like this:

```
create_table :my_models do |t|
  t.datetime :seen_at
  t.integer :some_number

  t.timestamps
end
```

Now, in the model I wanna specify a scope to get all entries where the following condition matches:

```
scope :test, -> { where("seen_at > ?", some_number.hours.ago) }
```

But that raises the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `some_number'
```

I've also tried `my_models.some_number.hours.ago`, but that doesn't fix my issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scope :test, -> (some_number)  { where("seen_at > ?", some_number.hours.ago) }`

Comment: Thx @radubogdan, but I don't wanna pass an argument to it ^^

Comment: Then how do you want to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Postgres you can do

```
scope :test, -> { where("seen_at > now() - (interval '1 hour' * some_number)") }
```